# How to store entire column values of the query result in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-variables

I have a statement,

```
select customer_id,count(customer_id), sum(total_price), date_time 
from the_order group by customer_id;
```

The Result,

```
cus1    15  437700  2021-04-23
cus2    1   12000   2008-5-9
cus3    1   13000   2009-5-9
cus4    1   14000   2006-5-9
```

Now as I have to use the `customer_id` to find other values from the database too. I want to store it in some variable and then use it to do other queries. But I have not found a way how to do that. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are storing `customer_id` in variable simply join other tables through customer id and select your desired columns.

Comment: While probably correct, this seems more like a comment than an answer

Comment: man I was thinking completely different thing. Join has incredible power. Thanks.
At least your comment helped.